# How to get all config parameters from a .scala file ?

Tags: scala, object, config

I want to call all the parameters from `BeamConfig.scala` in another scala class. The parameters stored in `BeamConfig.scala` are like below:

```
case class WarmStart(
  enabled: scala.Boolean,
  path: java.lang.String
)

object WarmStart {

  def apply(c: com.typesafe.config.Config): BeamConfig.Beam.WarmStart = {
    BeamConfig.Beam.WarmStart(
      enabled = c.hasPathOrNull("enabled") && c.getBoolean("enabled"),
      path = if (c.hasPathOrNull("path")) c.getString("path") else "output"
    )
  }
}
```

So There are more than 100 parameters object like above object in BeamConfig.scala. If I want to get the parameter from this file than I will do like this:

```
beam.warmStart.enable
beam.warmStart.path
```

Where beam is the root class.So is there any way so that i can call all the parameters in a bulk or I can store all the object in some Map or something else.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

there's a couple different ways you could do this:

Using Typesafe Config in a somewhat unsafe-ish manner:
https://github.com/lightbend/config#api-example

This would give you map-like access but it can very easily explode if the names are wrong, types don't line up etc.

Using PureConfig (a wrapper around typesafe config which allows automatic derivation of case class based config decoders, kinda like circe for json)
https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/

So you'd have to write you large caseclass with 100 fields once but you have a safe decoding of config into that case class and after that you have normal named properties with their correct types.

(Note that this will lose you invariance under rename refactor)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would separate the code that reads the config from the code that processes the results. In this case the default value `"output"` is embedded in the code that reads the config when it should probably be done in a separate pass.

Secondly, I would use a package to automatically populate a `case class` from a config entry. You then need one line per config object, and you get the results checked for you. E.g.

```
object BeamConfig {
  val warmStart = Config[WarmStart]("warmStart")
  val config2 = Config[Config2]("config2")
  ...
}
```

If you need some processing you can do this

```
val warmStart = ProcessWarmStart(Config[WarmStart]("warmStart"))
```

This approach still requires a bit of boiler plate code, but it has better type safety than a bulk import of the config.

I would also consider combining the objects into fewer, nested objects with matching nested case classes.

---

Here is a cut-down version of `Config` using `json4s` and `jackson`:

```
import com.typesafe.config._
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

object Config {
  private val cfgFile = "configFile"
  private val conf = ConfigFactory.load(cfgFile).withFallback(ConfigFactory.load())
  private val jData = parse(conf.root.render(ConfigRenderOptions.concise))

  def apply[T](name: String)(implicit formats: Formats = DefaultFormats, mf: Manifest[T]): T =
    Extraction.extract(jData \\ name)(formats, mf)
}
```

This will throw an exception if the particular config object does not exist or does not match the format of class `T`.