# Retrieving list of objects from application.conf

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I have the following entry in Play for Scala `application.conf`:

```
    jobs = [
       {number: 0, dir: "/dir1", name: "General" },
       {number: 1, dir: "/dir2", name: "Customers" }
    ]
```

I want to retrieve this list of objects in a Scala program:

```
    val conf = ConfigFactory.load
    val jobs = conf.getAnyRefList("jobs").asScala 
    println(jobs)
```

this prints

```
Buffer({number=0, name=General, dir=/dir1}, {number=1, name=Customers, dir=/dir2})
```

But how to convert the result to actual Scala objects?

Comment: I think you'd have to map over the buffer and manually parse out the fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all config parameters from a .scala file ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389913/how-to-get-all-config-parameters-from-a-scala-file)

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389913/how-to-get-all-config-parameters-from-a-scala-file/53391283#53391283) for code that extracts extracts config data as scala objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
case class Job(number: Int, dir: String, name: String)

object Job {
implicit val configLoader: ConfigLoader[List[Job]] = ConfigLoader(_.getConfigList).map(
    _.asScala.toList.map(config =>
      Job(
        config.getInt("number"),
        config.getString("dir"),
        config.getString("name")
      )
    )
  )
}
```

Then from Confugutation DI
`Configuration.get[List[Job]]("jobs")`

Comment: Something that threw me off - you may need to also `import scala.collection.JavaConverters.asScalaBufferConverter` to get `.asScala` to work (in case you find this answer through Google like me)

Comment: @JamesWhiteley of course, but also import depends on scala version you uses)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `Config` object which will extract data from a config file into a type that you specify.

Usage:

```
case class Job(number: Int, dir: String, name: String)

val jobs = Config[List[Job]]("jobs")
```

Code:

```
import com.typesafe.config._
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

object Config {
  private val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
  private val jData = parse(conf.root.render(ConfigRenderOptions.concise))

  def apply[T](name: String)(implicit formats: Formats = DefaultFormats, mf: Manifest[T]): T =
    Extraction.extract(jData \\ name)(formats, mf)
}
```

This will throw an exception if the particular config object does not exist or does not match the format of `T`.